# variables not working when in an object

Tags: jquery

So I want to set a couple of variables(datasets) to body tag, but when I combine them into an object the var names are not working.

// the code

```
var1 = 'data-var1'
var2 = 'data-var2'
var3 = 'data-var3'

$('body').attr({
   var1 : 1,
   var2 : 2,
   var3 : 3
});
```

// result after

```
<body var1="1" var2="2" var3="3">
```

Comment: The property names in an object literal are literals, not variables.

Comment: With JavaScript's object notation, `{foo: 'bar'}` and `{'foo': 'bar'}` are exactly the same object.

Comment: Try `{ "data-var1": 1, ... }`. Also check out jQuery's `.data()` for dealing with data- attributes.

Answer (score 1):

As some comments in your own questions have pointed out, the left part of a object property declaration is the name of the whole property and cannot be a variable.

If you want to achieve that result, you'll need to refactor your code to:

```
var var1 = "data-var1";
...

var attributes = {};
attributes[var1] = 1; // <-- You can use variables to add properties
                      // after object literal declaration!
...

$(body).attr(attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object literal for this, because the property names are treated literally. Use the two-argument form:

```
$('body').attr(var1, 1).attr(var2, 2).attr(var3, 3);
```